# How to update a specific object within storage with React/Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm considering using Redux for my app, but there's a common use case that I'm not sure how to handle with it. I have a component that displays some object and allows the user to edit it. Every action will create a shallow copy of the object, but what then? How is the component supposed to know how to update the storage with it? In the samples I see that the component is passed a key instead of the actual object, but doesn't that break the concept of incapsulation, since a component isn't supposed to know where it's state/props come from? I want the component to be fully reusable, so it receives an object and information on how to update it in a more general form, which seems to be awkward to implement with Redux (I'm going to have to pass write callbacks to every component, and then chain them somehow).

Am I using Redux wrong, or is there a more suitable alternative for this use case? I'm thinking of making one myself (where every state object knows it's owner and key via some global WeakMap), but I don't want to be reinventing the wheel.

For instance, if my storage looks like this:

```
Storage = {
  items: {
    item1: { ... },
    item2: { ... },
    ...
  },
  someOtherItems: {
    item1: { ... },
    ...
  },
  oneMoreItem: { ... },
};
```

I want to be able to display all `item` objects with the same component. But the component somehow has to know how to write it's updated item back to the storage, so I can't just pass it `item1` as key. I could pass a callback that would replace a specific item in the (cloned) storage, but that doesn't work well if, for instance, I have a component that displays a list of items, since I would have to chain those callbacks somehow.

Comment: Give use some code to look at.

Comment: It's more of a general question, since I haven't started porting my code to React yet, but I'll try to come up with something.

Comment: Please do, we'll be able to point it out more truthfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common use case, and yes - you're missing the point here. react/redux makes this really easy.

I usually structure it as follows: Components receive a `modelValue` object prop and `changeValue` function prop. The former is the current value, the latter is the function we call to change the value. These props are going to be supplied by redux.

Now we write a connect hoc (higher order component), a simple example might look like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    return {
        modelValue: _.get(state, ownProps.model),
    };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
    return {
        changeValue: (val) => dispatch({
            type: "your/reducer/action",
            model: ownProps.model,
            value: val,
        })
    };
};

const mergeProps = (stateProps, dispatchProps, ownProps) => {
    return {
        ...stateProps,
        ...dispatchProps,
        ...ownProps,
    };
};

const MyConnectedComponent = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, mergeProps)(MyGenericComponent);
```

This is an example where we pass in a `model` string to the hoc, and it wires up `modelValue` and `changeValue` for us. So now all we need to do is pass in a model like "some.javascript.path" to our component and that's where it will get stored in the state. `MyGenericComponent` still doesn't know or care about where it's stored in the state, only `MyConnectedComponent` does.

Usage would be as follows:

```
<MyConnectedComponent model="some.path.in.the.state" />
```

And inside `MyGenericComponent` just consume `modelValue` for the current value, and execute `changeValue` to change the value.

Note that you need to also wire up a redux reducer to handle `your/reducer/action` and actually do the update to the state, but that's [a whole other topic.](https://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html)

### Edit

You mentioned that you need sub components to be aware of the parent state, this can be achieved by passing model via context. The following examples are using recompose:

```
const mapStateToProps = ...

const mapDispatchToProps = ...

const mergeProps = ...

const resolveParentModel = (Component) => {
    return (props) => {
        // we have access to 'model' and 'parentModel' here.
        // parentModel comes from parent context, model comes from props
        const { parentModel, model } = props;

        let combinedModel = model;

        // if our model starts with a '.' then it should be a model relative to parent. 
        // else, it should be an absolute model.
        if (model.startsWith(".")) {
            combinedModel = parentModel + model;
        }

        return <Component {...props} model={combinedModel} />;
    }
}

const myCustomHoc = (Component) => (
    // retrieve the current parent model as a prop
    getContext({ parentModel: React.PropTypes.string })(
        // here we map parent model and own model into a single combined model
        resolveParentModel(
            // here we map that combined model into 'modelValue' and 'changeValue'
            connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, mergeProps)(
                // we provide this single combined model to any children as parent model so the cycle continues
                withContext({ parentModel: React.PropTypes.string }, (props) => props.model)(
                    Component
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

In summary, we pass a context value `parentModel` to all children. Each object maps parent model into it's own model string conditionally. Usage would then look like this:

```
const MyConnectedParentComponent = myCustomHoc(MyGenericParentComponent);
const MyConnectedSubComponent = myCustomHoc(MyGenericSubComponent);

<MyConnectedParentComponent model="some.obj">
    {/* the following model will be resolved into "some.obj.name" automatically because it starts with a '.' */}
    <MyConnectedSubComponent model=".name" />
</MyConnectedParentComponent>
```

Note that nesting this way could then go to any depth. You can access absolute or relative state values anywhere in the tree. You can also get clever with your model string, maybe starting with `^` instead of `.` will navigate backwards: so `some.obj.path` and `^name` becomes `some.obj.name` instead of `some.obj.path.name` etc.

Regarding your concerns with arrays, when rendering arrays you almost always want to render all items in the array - so it would be easy enough to write an array component that just renders X elements (where X is the length of the array) and pass `.0`, `.1`, `.2` etc to each item.

```
const SomeArray = ({ modelValue, changeValue }) => (
    <div>
        {modelValue.map((v, i) => <SomeChildEl key={i} model={"." + i} />)}

        <span onClick={() => changeValue([...modelValue, {}])} >Add New Item</span>
    </div>
);
```

Comment: How would `MyGenericComponent` create sub-components that display/modify a part of this state? Especially since it doesn't know the value of `model` string?

Comment: What do you mean? Each component that needs to display state should be connected using the same `connect` hoc

Comment: I mean if `MyConnectedComponent` contains a component that can display and modify an item's name, I can't just write `<TextField text="modelValue.name">`, since it wouldn't know how to write it back. I would need to pass it `some.path.in.the.state.name` somehow, but you said the component doesn't know about the `model` path?

Comment: Sure, give me a few minutes - i'll give you an example

Comment: Sure, this looks similar to what I had in mind overall, though I'm not particularly fond of using strings to describe object location - what if an index depends on some other value, then we'd have to compose the string/use templates (i.e. `\`some.path.in.the.state[${other.path.index}]\``), which seems ugly.

Comment: @riv does the added example fill your need? You can of course come up with your own substitute for a `model` string, but unfortunately I don't have any ideas for that case. Let me know if you come up with something!

Comment: Well, I was thinking of having a map that stores the parent and the key for every object in the state, which could be automatically maintained in numerous ways, but that would imply that all basic types would have to be stored in objects instead (i.e. `[object Number]` instead of an plain value), but it would allow everything to happen automatically behind the scenes, and I just pass objects like normal props. I'll think about which approach suits me better, thanks for the suggestions.